# IfPresentOrElse scenario in java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a scenario where I am using nested streams. PFB the code:

```java
    list.parallelStream()
        .filter(item -> productList.parallelStream()
            .anyMatch(product -> product.getProductName().equals(item.getProductName())
                 && item.getQuantity() <= product.getAvailableQuantity()));
```

Here I am trying to filter out based on the `productnames` which is working perfectly fine, but I need to add an else condition to anymatch. If there is no match found, I need to throw an error "*product not found*". I tried to use `ifPresentOrElse` but it takes `Consumer` interface as an argument which returns void(but in my case it has to return a boolean value). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `orElseThrow`?

Comment: I cannot use orElseThrow with a boolean value right? How do I incorporate it in my code?

Comment: "throw" throws an Exception type, you can't "throw" a boolean.

Comment: I mean orElseThrow is used along with Optional object, but in my case how do I use it

Comment: `findAny(...).orElseThrow(...)` instead of `anyMatch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-).

```
orElseThrow(ProductNotFoundException::new)
```

You can't use `orElseThrow()` with `anyMatch()` as it returns boolean.
You can use `findAny()` on the `filter()` which will return `Optional` and then you can throw exception using `orElseThrow()` on `Optional`.

For example :

```java
 list.parallelStream()
        .filter(item -> productList.parallelStream()
            .anyMatch(product -> product.getProductName().equals(item.getProductName())
                 && item.getQuantity() <= product.getAvailableQuantity()))
        .findAny().orElseThrow(ProductNotFoundException::new);
```

**Edit** :

OP wants to throw error on first product that is not found.

```java
        list.parallelStream()
                .filter(item -> {
                    if (productList.parallelStream().anyMatch(product -> product.getProductName().equals(item.getProductName())
                                    && item.getQuantity() <= product.getAvailableQuantity())) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        throw new ProductNotFoundException();
                    }
                });
```

Do add a terminal operation for the stream to execute.

Comment: I cannot use orElseThrow with a boolean value right? How do I incorporate it in my code?

Comment: What do you mean? You just write `findAny(...).orElseThrow(...)`, done.

Comment: Updated my answer to incorporate `orElseThrow` in OP's code

Comment: Updated answer and added explanation.

Comment: findAny() returns a single product but there could be more than one product  @Smile

Comment: If you want to collect all the values, you need to collect it first and then throw the exception based on its size. You can't check for size of the stream until you run a terminal operation.

Comment: I tried that but that will be a generic exception as Product not found but I am trying to throw an error for a specific product when it is not found

Comment: Do you want to throw an exception on first product not found?

Comment: Yes while iterating on the list of products, if the first product is not available it should throw an error

Comment: Don't think it is possible using single line operations on the stream. You need to put an if else. Updated my answer to reflect this.